# Bash - Executing a command in a script adding single quotes to a variable containing spaces

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am writing a script that executes all necessary commands to train a tesseract language and I want to receive a font as argument **(e.g.: DejaVu Sans Bold)** and execute this command `text2image --text=trainingFile.txt --outputbase=eng.DejaVuSansBold.exp0 --font='DejaVu Sans Bold' --fonts_dir=/usr/share/fonts`. Notice that `--font='DejaVu Sans Bold'` has the font name single quoted. Since I receive the font as an argument, I need to add the quotes and use the name.

After some different approaches, my "most effective" attempt was `text2image --text="${trainingTextFileName}" --outputbase="${languageCode}"."${fontNameWithoutBlanks}".exp0 --font="'""${fontName}""'" --fonts_dir=/usr/share/fonts`
  but it is still not working... ("languageCode" and "fontNameWithoutBlanks" are other variables).

After running the script with this line, I get a notification saying that the font is not recognized although it works perfectly when I execute it "manually" in the console.
Using `set -x` and `set +x` the line (of the script) looks like this: `text2image --text=contentTraint.txt --outputbase=gdfdd.DejaVuSansBold.exp0 '--font='\''DejaVu Sans Bold'\''' --fonts_dir=/usr/share/fonts`. I have no idea how to go away from the extra quotation added because of the spaces...

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Did you try `--font=\'${fontName}\'`?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Yes, I did... The output is the same. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be clear about the command you want to execute.  When you type

```
text2image --text=trainingFile.txt --outputbase=eng.DejaVuSansBold.exp0 \
    --font='DejaVu Sans Bold' --fonts_dir=/usr/share/fonts
```

to the shell, what happens is that the shell invokes the command `text2image` with 4 arguments: 
`--text=trainingFile.txt`,
`--outputbase=eng.DejaVuSansBold.exp0`,
`--font=DejaVu Sans Bold`, 
`--fonts_dir=/usr/share/fonts`.

The purpose of the single quotes is just to tell the shell that `--font=DejaVu Sans Bold` is only one argument.  In order to answer your question, though, we really need to know how you are executing the command (ie, you need to show some code).  If you have the font name in the variable `$font`, you could do:

```
text2image --text=trainingFile.txt --outputbase=eng.DejaVuSansBold.exp0 \
    --font="$font" --fonts_dir=/usr/share/fonts
```

If the font is passed to your script as an argument, you could do:

```
font=$1
text2image ... --font="$1" ...
```

If you are constructing the command more dynamically, you may need to do something else.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was all it needed to work! I'm speechless, I've lost so many hours with this and I just didn't try `"$font"` because I didn't know that single quotes would be perceived automatically...

Do you know why I was getting this output   '--font='\''DejaVu Sans Bold'\''' ?

Comment: `set -x` is very pedantic with its output, and is telling you that you were trying to pass the argument `--font="DejaVu Sand Bold"`  (ie, you were including the double quotes in the name of the font, rather than using them to describe the boundaries of the name.)